# Problemas ao enviar notificação

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Estou usando o seguinte código para enviar notificação a partir do android e não do console

```
public static void pushFCMNotification(String userDeviceIdKey) throws Exception
{

        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=AIzaSyCEwVIxZv_..._hHEmAO0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("to",userDeviceIdKey.trim());
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", "Enviando msg");   // Notification title
        info.put("body", "cadastrou"); // Notification body
        json.put("notification", info);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(json.toString());
        wr.flush();
        conn.getInputStream();

    }
```

Não aparece nenhum erro na aplicação, simplesmente o código é executado e não funciona.

> W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented W/EGL_emulation:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented W/System.err:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) W/System.err: 
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.alpha.tec.agendaonline.Evento.EventosCad.pushFCMNotification(EventosCad.java:188)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.alpha.tec.agendaonline.Evento.EventosCad$1.onClick(EventosCad.java:84)
>   W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorre pois você está tentando abrir uma conexão na `Thread` principal  da aplicação ( [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) ).

Neste caso é necessário executar esta operação em uma [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Segue um exemplo:

```
  public class AsyncConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        final String userDeviceIdKey = strings[0];
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=AIzaSyCEwVIxZv_..._hHEmAO0");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to",userDeviceIdKey.trim());
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("title", "Enviando msg");   // Notification title
            info.put("body", "cadastrou"); // Notification body
            json.put("notification", info);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();
            conn.getInputStream();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
   }
```

Para executar a operação chame da seguinte forma:

```
new AsyncConnection().execute(userDeviceIdKey);
```